# Unable to view designer option at all in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

First, This is literally my first time using Xamarin and I'm finding this particular issue quite frustrating. If I miss out any basic info, please bear with me, I have done my best.

I am trying to create a cross-platform app using a blank app template.

When I load up the .xaml files the designer view is not there. Most guides suggest this will be in the bottom right of the screen. I have checked in Tools > Options > XAML designer and the option to use this is ticked.

I have tried just creating an Android app instead of cross-platform but with the same results. I noticed there were no emulators in my android emulator manager so created a basic Nexus 5, still no difference.

I'm really stuck with this now and it's frustrating to fall at the first hurdle like this, am I doing something really simple wrong here?

I'm using VS 2017 V.15.3.3 and installed Xamarin yesterday

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the 'designer' which I call Previewer, your XAML files need to be compiled.

Please note that the previewer is really buggy and there is yet to drag-n-drop tool for designing XAML files.

However, you can use packages such as LiveXAML (paid) or free alternatives so that you can hot-reload your XAML designs.

Comment: Thanks, thats useful. Dont suppose I could chuck another at you, when I try compile I get some errors that are all around

he $(targetframeworkversion) for xamarin.forms.platform.android.dll (v7.1) is greater than the target framework version for your project(6.0)

Ive been into the SDK manager and downloaded upto and including Android 9 (API 28) but when I go into the properties there only options that appear here are Android 6, so I cant change my target framework.

Comment: Of course, I have marked that as accepted. It would make sense at this point in time as I cannot compile them yet